# Unit tests for following code with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

```
List<String> lineArray = new ArrayList<String>();
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:abc.txt");
InputStream in = resource.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.startsWith("#")) {
        lineArray.add(reader.readLine());           }
}
reader.close();
```

The above code is part of a function returning void, I'm able to mock Resource and ResourceLoader but not able to find a way to mock BufferedReader. I also want to mock the List and call Mockito.verify() on List.add().

Comment: You can mock the `Resource` to return a valid `InputStream` for arbitrary string data. Why can't you inspect `lineArray` after the method has finished? If `lineArray` is a local variable what is the point of this whole method if it does not return anything or modify any state?

Comment: There is a pattern: extract `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));` into a method with package visibility and override it into the test so that the class used in the test returns a mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is local to the method, there is no side effect for you to test. Then again, there is no obvious purpose to using this method in non-test code either, because you'd read the data into the list, and then discard it.

You would need to inject the list as a parameter to the method:

```
void yourMethod(List<String> lineArray) {
  Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:abc.txt");
  // ... etc.
}
```

And you can now test this by invoking `yourMethod` in your test, with a `List` parameter, that you can inspect afterwards.

> I also want to mock the List and call Mockito.verify() on List.add().

*There is essentially no need to mock a List*, especially for this purpose: inject a list, a regular `ArrayList`, and just check that the list has grown by 1 after the method call.